# How do I turn a row into a column in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a txt file that reads:

```
exam1    exam2    final
87       85       90
90       95       89
73       81       85
98       93       94
78       76       82
```

I need to do this:

[['exam1', 87, 90, 73, 98, 78], ['exam2', 85, 95, 81, 93, 76], ['final', 90, 89, 85, 94, 82]]

This is the code I have:

```
f = open("scores.txt", "r")
st = f.readline()
print(st)
st.split() 
a = []
a = f.readline()
print(a)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

with open('scores.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()

print(content)
# prints just string

print(content.splitlines())
# ['exam1    exam2    final', '87       85       90', '90       95       89', '73       81       85', '98       93       94', '78       76       82']

print([c.split() for c in content.splitlines()])
# [['exam1', 'exam2', 'final'], ['87', '85', '90'], ['90', '95', '89'], ['73', '81', '85'], ['98', '93', '94'], ['78', '76', '82']]


list1 = [c.split() for c in content.splitlines()]

# transpose onliner ;)
print(list(map(list, zip(*list1))))
# [['exam1', '87', '90', '73', '98', '78'], ['exam2', '85', '95', '81', '93', '76'], ['final', '90', '89', '85', '94', '82']]

# if You have lists of different sizes this may suit better
print(list(map(list, zip_longest(*list1))))
```

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! How would i do it without having to import anything?

Comment: If your lists are all the same length, just use the version with `zip`, and no need to import `zip_longest`.

Comment: Thank you! my lists are the same length but how about without using zip? maybe list comprehension?